# My code is not going to getView() of Extended Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I want to list multiple layout records in one listview. For this, I fetched my data from web service and loaded that to my custom VO class Object. Then, it was handling my two types of row data. I'm passing that to my adapter but it is not generating the custom listview data. Here is my code.

Adapter :

```
public class FeedsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VO_BaseFeedHolder> {

    VO_BaseFeedHolder                   _mBaseFeedHolder;
    ArrayList<VO_CDobFeedHolder>        _cDobHolder;
    ArrayList<VO_CRateFeedHolder>       _cRateHolder;
    final Object mLock                  = new Object();
    protected LayoutInflater            _mInflator;
    private static final int TYPE_RATING = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_DOB    = 1;

    public FeedsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<VO_BaseFeedHolder> mBaseFeedHolder) {
        super(context, R.layout.dashboard,mBaseFeedHolder);         

        this._mBaseFeedHolder   = mBaseFeedHolder.get(0);
        this._cDobHolder        = _mBaseFeedHolder.dobFeeds;
        this._cRateHolder       = _mBaseFeedHolder.ratingFeeds;
        this._mInflator         = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    static class FeedsViewHolder {

        // BIRTHDAY COMPONENTS
        public ImageView _feedIcon;
        public TextView _phrase;
        public TextView _timeStamp;
        public TextView _like;
        public TextView _protobox;
        public boolean _isRating;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        synchronized (mLock) {

        }
        return 0;
    };

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return TYPE_DOB;
    };

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;       
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("IN","IN TO GETVIEW");
        View rowView = convertView;
        FeedsViewHolder fvholder = new FeedsViewHolder();
        int type     = getItemViewType(position);
        if (rowView == null) {
            switch(type) {
            case TYPE_RATING:
                rowView = _mInflator.inflate(R.layout.dashboardfrate, null);
                fvholder._feedIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingpic);
                fvholder._phrase   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingphrase);
                fvholder._timeStamp= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingtimestamp);
                fvholder._isRating = true;
                break;
            case TYPE_DOB:
                rowView = _mInflator.inflate(R.layout.dashboardfdob, null);
                //fvholder = new FeedsViewHolder();
                fvholder._feedIcon  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.birthdaypic);
                fvholder._phrase    = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.birthdayphrase);
                fvholder._like      = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.birthdaylike);
                fvholder._isRating  = false;                
                break;
            }

            rowView.setTag(fvholder);
        } else {
            fvholder = (FeedsViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        if(fvholder._isRating == false) {
            Log.i("INTO fvHolder","TRUE");
            VO_CDobFeedHolder _mdobRecord = this._cDobHolder.get(position);
            Log.i("_mDob",_mdobRecord._userid);
            fvholder._phrase.setText("The Record by "+_mdobRecord._userid);
            fvholder._like.setTag(_mdobRecord._userid);
        } else {
            VO_CRateFeedHolder _mRateRecord = this._cRateHolder.get(position);
            fvholder._phrase.setText("RATING COMMENT: "+_mRateRecord._comments);
            fvholder._timeStamp.setText(_mRateRecord._timestamp);
        }
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
FeedLoader();
private void FeedLoader() {
             String[] params = new String[] {};
             try {
                this.mvoBaseFeedHolder = new FetchFeedTask().execute(params).get();
                this._collection.add(mvoBaseFeedHolder);
                setListAdapter(new FeedsAdapter(this,this._collection));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i("INTURRPTED",e.toString());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.i("Execution",e.toString());
            }
     }
```

VO_BaseFeedHolderis here:

```
public class VO_BaseFeedHolder {

    ArrayList<VO_CDobFeedHolder> dobFeeds;
    ArrayList<VO_CRateFeedHolder> ratingFeeds;

    public VO_BaseFeedHolder(ArrayList<VO_CDobFeedHolder> _dobObject,ArrayList<VO_CRateFeedHolder> _rateObject) {
        dobFeeds        =  _dobObject;
        ratingFeeds     =  _rateObject;
    }

}
```

VO_CDobFeedHolder:

```
public class VO_CDobFeedHolder {

    String _userid, _date;

    public VO_CDobFeedHolder(String userid,String date) {
        this._userid    = userid;
        this._date      = date;
    }
}
```

VO_CRateFeedHolder:

```
public class VO_CRateFeedHolder {

    final String _userid,_projectid,_responder,_stars,_comments,_timestamp;

    public VO_CRateFeedHolder(String userid, String projectid,String responder,String stars,String comments,String timestamp) {
        this._userid = userid;
        this._projectid = projectid;
        this._responder = responder;
        this._stars = stars;
        this._comments = comments;  
        this._timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

Can anyone let me get of this situation. Need help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your

```
  @Override
public int getCount() {
    synchronized (mLock) {

    }
    return 0;
};
```

is returning `0`. Let's return the number of item you need to display

Comment: It works man! really nice. I want one thing more. Now, I want to create the listview item randomly. Like, I have two VO objects and both have different data records as you saw in adapter. Now, I want that the listview would be generated over the random record rows over those 2 Child VOs and then get the layout from inflator. Please help again.

Comment: can you fill mBaseFeedHolder with randomatic data?

Comment: mBaseFeedHolder is filled with 2 VO. Rate and DOB. Both are ArrayList<type> and filled with record indexes.